# Compute; $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1-y^{x-1}\frac{x-1}{2})xy^{x-1}}{1-xy^{x-1}}$ with $0 \leq y <1$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Prove that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1-y^{x-2}\frac{x-1}{2})xy^{x-1}}{1-xy^{x-1}}=1$$ where $x \in \mathbb{N}$ ($x \neq 0$) and $0 \leq y <1$.

I have managed to to multiply by $\frac{2}{2}$ to get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{[2-y^{x-1}(x-1)]xy^{x-1}}{2-2xy^{x-1}}$$
And then, through expanding and rearranging :
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(2-2xy^{x-1})xy^{x-1}+x^{2}y^{2x-2}+xy^{2x-2}}{2-2xy^{x-1}}$$
Which obviously results in :
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{xy^{x-1}}{2-2xy^{x-1}}+\frac{x^{2}y^{2x-2}+xy^{2x-2}}{2-2xy^{x-1}}\bigg)$$

However I don’t know how to go on from here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE !  Why downvote?

Comment: @GNUSupporter There is a big problem with downvotes in this forum the time being (have experienced it too). Don't pay attention to it, this is a perfectly asked question. Flag any post you think that gets downvoted for no reason and moderators will look into it !

Comment: if $0\leq y<1$, how does it go to infinity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case $y=0$ trivialy gives zero. Let $y>0$

Now since $0<y<1\implies \ln y<0$ then

$$\color{red}{\lim_{x\to\infty } (x-1)\ln y =-\infty}$$ 
then, we have,

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}   \frac{x-1}{2}y^{x-1} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-1}{2}\exp\left((x-1)\ln y\right) \\\overset{\color{blue}{u=(x-1)\ln y}}{=}\frac{1}{2\ln y}\lim_{\color{red}{u\to-\infty}}u\exp\left(u\right) =0.$$

Similarly,  $$ \lim_{x\to\infty}xy^{x-1}  =0$$
Hence, 
$$\color{blue}{\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1-y^{x-1}\frac{x-1}{2})xy^{x-1}}{1-xy^{x-1}}=0} $$